# Popup submit button does not work

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a popup panel with a submit button but the form submission doesn't work.

```
<p align="left">
    <h:commandButton value="Management" style="font-size: 20px">
        <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
    </h:commandButton>
</p>

<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Please Login for forther process" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide();
                return false;">
            X
        </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
    <p>
        <h:form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="User Name"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{abc.name}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Password"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{abc.password}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{abc.submit()}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </p>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Why doesn't `abc.submit()` function work?

Comment: Do you have nested forms? If yes remove them.

Comment: Also remove brackets from action: `action=#{beanName.action}`. They are unnecessary.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Did you do anything we asked?